# Transaction to Coinbase not showing up in account

Tags: coinbase.com

On 26th and 31st of January I transferred each 1 BTC (total of 2 BTC) from my Blockchain wallet to my Coinbase wallet. On the Blockchain site they show up as confirmed transfers. However, on the  Coinbase page they do not show up in my wallet. A 0.10 BTC transfer in December showed up right away.

There are phone numbers and e-mail addresses on the Blockchain site, I can't find anything on the Coinbase site.

Is there any way to reach the Coinbase site to inquire about the transfer?

Answer (score 1):

CoinBase has a support portal where you can open a case: https://coinbase.desk.com/customer/portal/private/cases.

You have to log in with your CoinBase account to see this page.